# Host Not Accessible

Tags: ipv4

A strange thing happened recently. I have a few servers that have statics IP's and I can not longer access the servers. I cannot ping or trace them. However, I can go to their web portals. Each server has a web portal on a different port and I can access the server fine. I also noticed that any new IP's are not accessible either. I have tried rebooting the router, rebooting the switch, and shut down everything. I am at a loss right now. What would cause me to stop having access to IP's?

Comment: firewall? (the built-in windows firewall can often be the source of such reports)

Comment: Could the windows firewall block outgoing pings as well? I fired up a linux box and it received a new ip but i was still unable to ping it.

Comment: We need a lot more information to help you.  Can you provide a simple diagram?  Also, I would like to see your router configuration.  If this was working before, what has changed since then?

Comment: I disabled the firewall on my hosts and it started working. So strange, nothing has changed.

Comment: Obviously you want to look at anything that could interfere or change your configuration in regards to ICMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your host operating systems check if they block ICMP traffic. On GNU/Linux add two rules to your firewall rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Adapt as needed.